# Running code after i perform a segue?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Is there a way I can run code after `performSegueWithIdentifier`? So a button performs a segue to view controller 2 and in view controller 2 I want it to execute "refresh" code (populating its table view via parse.com).

Right now I have the "refresh" code in view controller 2's `viewDidAppear`, but changing it to perform the "refresh" code after doing the segue would reduce API requests.

Answer (score 3):

You typically use `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)` to execute code before the segue is executed, or `viewDidLoad()` for code that you want to execute when the segue is finished.

For finer control, you could subclass `UIStoryboardSegue` and create a custom segue, but it doesn't sound like you need that for this issue.

Comment: after a segue the table only reloads the tableview when i have the table refresh code in view did appear, i guess ill leave it there

Comment: @user42541 You should reload the table view after the data has downloaded.